# I need help with the battery Icon

Tags: 12.10, indicator, power-management, battery, acpi

I have a Toshiba Satellite L645D running Ubuntu 12.10 and it seems like Ubuntu like some other distros (Nadia, Debian) won't recognize my battery and I don't know the reason for that, it won't show the level of charge and if I have my laptop plugged in with the AC adapter, I have tried this "Settings > Power - Show battery status in the menu bar" as Always but it won't show me the level of charge at any moment i think the whole OS won't recognize the battery at all, help please, I'm desperate because every time I'm running the laptop with the battery eventually will discharge completely and turn off without even warning about battery level. I don't want to go back to Windows 7 and I have also asked this question in Spanish forums (As I'm a Spanish native talker) but no one seems to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are several questions related to this issue on the site already.  Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197394/toshiba-l750-22z-battery-icon-missing

Comment: Same problem here. Reinstalling `indicator-power` didn't help.

Comment: Your machine isn't supported probably, I guess. These bugs are called ACPI bugs and are very hard to squash. I can only recommend dumping the raw DSDT ACPI table to a file: `acpidump -b -t DSDT -o myDSDT.aml` and attaching this to a bug report. [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/88802) Anyway, just to verify, post the output of `dmesg | grep -i acpi` and `upower -d` from a terminal. Thanks :)

Comment: @gertvdijk where should I post that info?

Comment: @Inkbug In case you have the exact same laptop as the OP, just post it on paste.ubuntu.com and edit the question with a link to it. :) If you have a similar issue on other hardware, I would put the link in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**`sudo apt-get install indicator-power`**

If it is installed, try re-installing it.

**`sudo apt-get purge indicator-power`**

**`sudo apt-get install indicator-power`**

Comment: @Benjamin Osorio Have you tried the above steps? If yes what was the output? if you could mention more details then it would give others to understand and can know what can be done further.

Comment: Doing this (multiple times) hasn't helped me, with a similar computer and setup.